# Аналог "foot in the door"

Tags: from-english, фразеологізми

Маючи складний спосіб робити щось ми знайшли щось, що дає нам легкий спосіб це робити, тобто якби поставили ногу в привідкриті двері і їх вже не закриєш.

Ось стаття на тему [Техніка «Нога в дверях»](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0_%C2%AB%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%85%C2%BB). Але може є питомий варіант, який каже те саме.

Comment: Тут, мені здається, акцент не на тому, що був складний спосіб щось робити, а ми знайшли простіший — а на тому, що ми зробили щось, заклали якусь основу, після якої далі йти легше (це я зараз не про психологічну техніку «нога в дверях», а про те, в якому сенсі цей вираз уживається в книзі — як я зрозумів, довели щось, що «відкрило шлях» для подальших доведень).

Comment: @Sasha шлях був і до цього, але складніший

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я так розумію, суть у тому, що ми зробили щось, після чого стало можливим (або стало значно легшим) інше (чи навіть багато чого іншого).

Можна спробувати щось типу такого:

- відкрили шлях;
- заклали основу/фундамент;
- зробили зачин;
- прорубали вікно;
- розв'язали руки.

Або якісь комбінації чи інші варіанти:

> Це фактично розв'язало нам руки. Адже тепер ми можемо *щось*.
>
> Цим ми відкрили двері до *чогось*.
>
> Цим ми зробили зачин, що відкрив нам шлях до *чогось*.
>
> Цим ми заклали фундамент для легкої побудови *чогось*.
>
> Цим ми фактично прорубали собі шлях. Адже тепер ми можемо *щось*.